# Notify_url in Paypal text link is not working

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I read at one of the Stackoverflow that the following URL can be use to make payment via paypal.
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=youremail@goeshere.tld&amount=1.00&currency_code=GBP&item_name=tripdatagoeshere

I look at the documentation that it accept notify_url which paypal will send a POST to after payment is successful. I tried but couldn't. Does paypal support this?

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=youremail@goeshere.tld&amount=1.00&currency_code=GBP&item_name=tripdatagoeshere&notify_url=http://www.s.com/d/notify.php

Comment: Did you check the IPN history of the seller account to see if it shows anything was sent?

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather old-school way to integrate with PayPal; I think the company generally steers people to the Website Payments Standards button factory/posts with hidden fields to access this functionality rather than putting parameters right in the URL. That said, any parameter you can send in a button post can also be sent in a plain GET URL, so yes you should be able to pass in a notify_url directly in the GET parameters as you show above.

However, the notify_url is intended only to override the selling account's normal notification URL. You need to set up a notification URL in your profile in order to turn the feature on; I believe a transaction-specific override URL will be ignored if the feature is not enabled. Once you turn on the IPN feature you should be able to override it this way... but you also might not need to, unless you want the postback URL to vary for each payment.

See also the WPS integration guide: https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/GB/en_GB/files/developer/PP_WebsitePaymentsStandard_IntegrationGuide.pdf

and the IPN guide: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/

Comment: +1 but I believe you can turn on IPN for your account without specifying a permanent notify URL.